# Volley Login task giving me this exception com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley

I am trying to login using volley but I keep getting this error:

> com.android.volley.ServerError and also this block of code does not get executed

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                            attemptLogin();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } }
```

it skips straight to the errorlistener. This is the code I am using:

```
UserLoginTask() {
        username = mEmailView.getText().toString().trim();
        password = mPasswordView.getText().toString().trim();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.BASE_URL.concat(Constants.CONSULTANT_KEY_WORD),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                            attemptLogin();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                return map;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: have u tried this with postman?

Comment: Are you sure your API is working?

Comment: does url have any extension? e.g url.php